# Incorrect integer value for INET_ATON

Tags: mysql, integer, sql-insert

When I try to insert an IP into my database as an integer using the INET_ATON function:

```
insert into network (NwID,IP,Subnetz) values ('1','INET_ATON(127.0.0.1)','INET_ATON(255.255.255.0)');
```

it tells me that it's getting an incorrect integer value (error 1366). This is my table:

```
NwID: Type:int(11) Null:NO Key:PRI Default:NULL 
IP: Type:int(11) unsigned NUll:NO Default:NULL
Subnetz: Type:int(11) unsigned NUll:NO Default:NULL
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: insert into network (NwID,IP,Subnetz) values ('1',INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'),INET_ATON('255.255.255.0'));

Comment: EDIT: It worked! I still had a trigger I didn't delete from before, thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
insert into network (NwID,IP,Subnetz) values ('1',INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'),INET_ATON('255.255.255.0'));
```

Comment: Why do you my comment answer copy??? You said it's not working. So why you answer the question. You should delete your answer.

Comment: Because I still had a trigger in my db, I had forgot about. That's why the IP was null. After deleting the trigger your command worked, so it, objectively, was the right answer to my question.

Comment: Ok. It's fine for you.